# Determining if a problem is solvable by a Push-Down Automaton

Tags: computer-science

I have the following language:

```
{0^n 1^n 0^n 1^n | n >=0}
```

And need to find a PDA that recognizes the language.

I have devised PDAS which determine

```
{0^n 1^n 0^m 1^m}
```

And

```
{0^n 1^m 0^m 1^n}
```

But haven't found one to solve the original problem. Is the problem solvable by a PDA with a single stack?

My approach has been.

At first, for the first series of 0s to add each of them to the stack.

Ie for input: 00001...

The stack would initially be:

00001...

However, at this point to check if the number of 1s matches that of 0s I need to remove one 0 from the stack for every 1 input until I reach an empty stack. Having an empty stack, I cannot check if the next series of 0s matches the number of 1s.

Suggestions?

Comment: That language doesn't look context-free to me.

Comment: This one is not context-free. What kind of non-context free languages do you know? (E.g. do you know $\{a^nb^nc^nd^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$?)

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is correct; the language 
$$
L=\{\mathtt{0}^n\mathtt{1}^n\mathtt{0}^n\mathtt{1}^n\mid n\ge 0\}
$$
is not context-free. Your informal argument—that we could use the stack to match up the first groups of $\mathtt{0}$s and  $\mathtt{1}$s but then we've lost track of how many there were—is good, but of course isn't a proof.

For a proof, let's take a nearly-identical language
$$
L_1=\{\mathtt{a}^n\mathtt{b}^n\mathtt{c}^n\mathtt{d}^n\mid n\ge 0\}
$$
where $\mathtt{a}\ne \mathtt{b}, \mathtt{b}\ne \mathtt{c}, \mathtt{c}\ne \mathtt{d}$. If we could show this isn't a CFL then we could conclude that the original language, $L$, wasn't a CFL.

The next step depends, as dtldarek noted, upon whether or not you know that 
$$
L_2=\{\mathtt{a}^n\mathtt{b}^n\mathtt{c}^n\mid n\ge 0\}
$$
isn't a CFL. If you know that fact, you can pass to the next step. If you don't, then you can ask about a proof using the Pumping Lemma for context-free languages, and I'll be happy to expand my answer. For now, let's simply accept that $L_2$ isn't context-free.

Now assume, to the contrary, that $L_1$ was a CFL. Consider the language 
$$
R=\{\mathtt{a}, \mathtt{b},\mathtt{c}\}^* 
$$ 
namely the set of all strings over the alphabet $\{\mathtt{a}, \mathtt{b}, \mathtt{c}\}$. This is clearly a regular language. We know that the intersection of two CFLs isn't necessarily a CFL, but the intersection of a CFL and a regular language will always be a CFL. Keep this in mind and note that
$$
L_2=L_1\cap R
$$
and if $L_1$ were a CFL, then we'd have that $L_2$, being the intersection of a CFL and a regular language, would have to be a CFL, which it isn't. Thus, we conclude that $L_1$ isn't a CFL and so your original language, $L$, isn't either.